# Batch Incremented File Rename

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to rename each file I have in a directory to an incremented value based on the current directory listing, so that

```
 -------------------------
|-------------------------|
|      | B1S1A800.ext     |
|      | B100M803.ext     |
|      | B100N807.ext     |
|      | B101S800.ext     |
|      | B102S803.ext     |
 -------------------------
```

Would instead look like:

```
 -------------------------
|-------------------------|
|      | 1.ext            |
|      | 2.ext            |
|      | 3.ext            |
|      | 4.ext            |
|      | 5.ext            |
 -------------------------
```

How would one go about achieving this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a way:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\yourpath\*.ext
$id = 1
$files | foreach {
Rename-Item -Path $_.fullname -NewName (($id++).tostring() + $_.extension) 
}
```